# unable to sum up using seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a set of data which have different category under the same type. I want to sum up the amount under different category which are under the same type. I have tried to sum up by using groupby to appear as box plot diagram.
The final output should be 2 box plot diagram (1 for total sum under operating and 1 for total sum under development for each year).
The error message is
ValueError: Cannot subset columns with a tuple with more than one element. Use a list instead.

```
import seaborn as sns 
from matplotlib import  axes
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

expense_df = pd.read_csv("Expenses.csv")
expense_df.head()

# setting the dimensions of the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 7))

# perform groupby 
#grouped_data = expense_df.groupby(['category'])
#sum_values = grouped_data['Utilities', 'Rental', 'Salary'].sum()

# subset the gapminder data frame for rows with year values 1952 and 2007
df1 = expense_df[expense_df['type'].isin(['Operating','Development'])]
df1.head()

sns.boxplot(y='amount', x='financial_year', 
                 data=df1, 
                 palette="colorblind",
                 hue='type')

ax = sns.countplot(x="financial_year", data=df1)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=40, ha="right")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: dataset]

Can someone advise where have I done wrongly?

Comment: Please post a sample of your dataframe (not as image)

Comment: If you get an error, please clearly indicate which line of the code causes the error. If the error isn't clear from the direct code and the error message, please also include the full error trace (as text, never as image).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to have [barplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) for that, not boxplot (this would require a distribution of datapoints, but you only want to display a single datapoint per year).

To get the desired result, you can first group the data by `financial_year` and `type`, sum the amount and convert the resulting multi-index series [back to a dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.to_frame.html).

[image]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "financial_year": [1997] * 5 + [1998] * 5,
        "type": ["Operating"] * 3 + ["Development"] * 2 + ["Operating"] * 3 + ["Development"] * 2,
        "category": ["Utilities", "Rental", "Salary", "Development Expenditure", "Development Expenditure"] * 2,
        "amount": [1000, 5000, 9807, 5326, 3637, 1000, 5000, 10989, 7687, 2763],
    }
)

grouped_data = df.groupby(["financial_year", "type"])["amount"].sum()
sns.barplot(
    data=grouped_data.to_frame(),
    x="financial_year",
    y="amount",
    hue="type",
)
plt.show()
```